# Does .GroupBy() guarantee order in its groupings?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects, ilookup

Say I have an (ordered) sequence of animals:

```
Eagle
Elephant
Tarantula
Terrapin
Tiger
```

and I group by first letter:

```
Animals.GroupBy(animal => animal.First())
```

will the elements of the `IGrouping`s in the resulting sequence be in the same order as the input sequence?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, they will be: [GroupBy (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501).

> The IGrouping<TKey, TElement> objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping<TKey, TElement>.  Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.

Answer (score 14):

Quote from the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) for GroupBy:

> The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`. Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order they appear in source.

So your example will result in:

> 1. Group 1
>
>    - Eagle
>    - Elephant
> 2. Group 2
>
>    - Tarantula
>    - Terrapin
>    - Tiger

Of course that only applies to the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation.  The `IQueryable<T>` implementation has no such guarantee.