# Linq lambda expression to get at least one duplicate along with non duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
List<Dev> devices= new List<Dev>(){
    new Dev{ Add="5",Name="A" },
    new Dev{ Add="5",Name="a" },
    new Dev{ Add="9",Name="b" },
    new Dev{ Add="6",Name="c" },
    new Dev{ Add="9",Name="b" },

};
```

I want to write a Linq "Lambda Expression" which return the records that are not duplicates and also the first record from duplicates based on "Name" in the list. Also ignore case while finding duplicates

Expected Output:

```
Add=5, Name=A
Add=9, Name=b
Add=6, Name=c
```

Query what I have now (It returns the "Name" which is duplicate):

```
results.GroupBy(x => x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Just grab first record from each group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pretty close: rather than picking `g.Key`, pick `g.First()`, and remove filtering by count:

```
var list = results.GroupBy(x => x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                  .Select(g => g.First())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it specified that Enumerable.GroupBy keeps the original Order? Or could it be that in group 5 the first element is the one with the name 'a', with 'A' as second? In that cast this answer does not return the requested object

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse [Yes, LINQ guarantees the order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377922/335858).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I believe we can also use "x=>x.Name.ToLower()" instead of "StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase". So, which one should we go with for better performance and accuracy?

Comment: @DotNetDev `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` looks cleaner, because it avoids creating temporary `string` objects that are used for grouping, and then promptly discarded.