# Restructuring an object into a different type

Tags: c#, object

I have an SQL database with data on walking statistics.

I am extracting the data from SQL into C# into a List of "Transaction". Transaction is a class that represents the amount of kilometers walked by some person during some day i.e.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Transaction(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime date, int kilomtersWalked)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Date = date;
        KilometersWalked = kilomtersWalked;
    }
  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int KilometersWalked { get; set; }

}
```

I populate the list from SQL, but to illustrate the data I will instantiate it with hardcoded values here.

```
List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>
        {
            new Transaction("Michael", "Smith", new DateTime(2021, 01, 01), 5),
            new Transaction("Michael", "Smith", new DateTime(2021, 01, 02), 8),
            new Transaction("Michael", "Smith", new DateTime(2021, 01, 03), 7),
            new Transaction("Hillary", "Johnson", new DateTime(2021, 01, 01), 12),
            new Transaction("Hillary", "Johnson", new DateTime(2021, 01, 02), 3),
            new Transaction("Hillary", "Johnson", new DateTime(2021, 01, 03), 6)
        };
```

I would like to convert the data into a List of "PersonStats". PersonStats is a class that represents the amount of kilometers walked by a specific person, not just on one day, but on every day i.e

```
public class PersonStats
{
    public PersonStats(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime[] dates, int[] kilomtersWalked)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Dates = dates;
        KilometersWalked = kilomtersWalked;
    }
  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] Dates { get; set; }
    public int[] KilometersWalked { get; set; }

}
```

Although I put a lot of effort into it, I still haven't been able to come up with an elegant way of doing this. Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you plan to store it persistently? Or are we just computing it every time the app runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create instances of `PersonStats` by grouping on the FirstName and LastName. It would be better to introduce a unique ID for each person and group by that instead since there are plenty of Michael Smiths in the world.

```
var ps = transactions
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.FirstName, g.LastName })
    .Select(g => new PersonStats(
        g.Key.FirstName, 
        g.Key.LastName, 
        g.Select(_ => _.Date).ToArray(),
        g.Select(_ => _.KilometersWalked).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Note that independently selecting Date and KilometersWalked will still pair up the correct date and distance. The order in GroupBy is stable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377922/141172

Comment: Thank you Eric, this solution works perfect for me! Do you also happen to have a suggestion on how I can go back from the grouped object of PersonStats and back to a list of Transaction?

Comment: Have a look at `SelectMany()` to write a query that reverses this.